# Regular expressions not working on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write some SQL code (on SQL Server 2008) to take a column and replace the entries if the cell fits a regular expression pattern. Basically, if a cell in a column has the form C12345 (the letter C followed by five digits) I want to drop the C. Otherwise, I want to leave the cell alone. Here's the code I've tried:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (
CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'C[0-9]{5, 5}' THEN SUBSTRING(column1, 1, 5)
ELSE column1
END
);
```

This doesn't produce any errors, but it doesn't affect any of the rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct.  SQL Server does not support regular expressions out of the box.  No news there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can express what you want as:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET column1 = (CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
                        THEN SUBSTRING(column1, 2, 5)
                        ELSE column1
                   END);
```

SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions out-of-the-box.  It does have an extended `like`.  I assume the above is what you want, although you might want `%` before the `C` (to be more consistent with the regular expression you used).

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (
CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'C%' 
AND (ISNULL(TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(column1,2,100) as INT),-1) BETWEEN 0 AND 99999)
THEN SUBSTRING(column1, 1, 5)
ELSE column1
END
);
```

**Hack:**
The trick here is to first check for C as first letter and then if present check for a 5 digit number. I extract the remaining digits after C using `SUBSTRING(column1,2,100)`. Note that 100 is just really high value so that i get everything from `column1` after C.
 Next step is to use TRY_CAST to convert to INT if numeric, otherwise -1 which fails range

Comment: Do note that SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `try_convert()`.